# ipython pylab figures not inline

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I've installed iPython + SciPy Superpack on a Mac (OSX Lion).

If I plot using matplotlib.pyplot, it will pop up a window with the graph, and I close this for the ipython kernel to continue.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9])
plt.show()
```

However, If I try the inline (starting with `--pylab inline` or `--pylab=inline`) and import pylab, instead of a plot inside the notebook (which I expect), I get an external window, which never renders anything.

Still in an external window:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9])
pylab.show()
```

Since I've started the notebook with `ipython notebook --pylab=inline` it should already be so, but if I use `%pylab inline` in a cell and run it, I get the help, and the same code above creates a blank window, and hangs the kernel - I can only force kill the window.
How should this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay - the problem was that the original ipython notebook process was still running (I'd not killed it) and the new one with the inline flag was running on a different port.

If you are having this issue - first save all your notebooks, then check you haven't got other processes running and kill any that shouldn't be running.

If you want to avoid this confusion, you can set `NotebookApp.port_retries=0` in your configuration, in which case later notebook calls will give up, rather than listen on a new port. (Credit to [minrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938949/minrk), in comments)

Comment: If you want to avoid this confusion, you can set `NotebookApp.port_retries=0` in your configuration, in which case later notebook calls will give up, rather than listen on a new port.